# How to get every nth element in group (starting with #n)? - updated

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**changes bolded**

---

I need to run some jquery on a group of divs. I have the following html **code updated**:

```
    <div class="tile_set" id="tile-set" style="width: 984px;">
    <div id="tile_id_437" class="product_tile">
        <div class="tile tile_front" style="display: block;">
            <h1>Buffalo Burnin' Hot</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile_back" style="display: none;">                          
            <h1 class="title">Buffalo Burnin' Hot</h1>
            <p class="description">Extreme heat for the daring Buffalo eater.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tile_id_438" class="product_tile">
        <div class="tile tile_front" style="display: block;">
            <h1>Buffalo Medium</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile_back" style="display: none;">                          
            <h1 class="title">Buffalo Medium</h1>
            <p class="description">Medium heat</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tile_id_439" class="product_tile">
        <div class="tile tile_front" style="display: block;">
            <h1>Buffalo Mild</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile_back" style="display: none;">                          
            <h1 class="title">Buffalo Mild</h1>
            <p class="description">No heat</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tile_id_440" class="product_tile">
        <div class="tile tile_front" style="display: block;">
            <h1>Honey BBQ</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="tile tile_back" style="display: none;">                          
            <h1 class="title">Honey BBQ</h1>
            <p class="description">Sweet BBQ</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**I need to run my code on the tile_back div that's a child of every nth product_tile div**, starting at n. (The value of n can change.) For example, one time I need to run code on every fourth element, starting with the fourth (or third, if you're using base 0.) So with this example, the code would run on Tile 4 and Tile 8, but not Tile 1. Another time, I need to run the same code on every third item, so Tile 4 and Tile 8, but again not Tile 1.

I've tried using

```
$("#tile_set .product_tile:nth-child(4n)");
```

but that gets me Tiles 2, 4, 6, and 8. I ONLY want 4 and 8 in this case.

What I need is a way to pass in a value of n and have it return the tiles that match (if I pass in 3, return 3/6/9; if I pass in 4, return 4/8.)

Is this possible?

Comment: What you suggest is correct - there must be something else causing the problem... [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdBzH/)

Comment: @Archer, you're right - I stripped down the html to make it easier to read, but there's another level in there. I'm updating the OP to show the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `tile_back` divs, you can use:

```
$(".tile_back", ".product_tile:nth-child(4n)")
```

E.g. to print out the text in the `<p>` element in each of them, you can do:

```
$(".tile_back > p", ".product_tile:nth-child(4n)").text();
```